# Что означает эта строчка кода в java?

Tags: android, java

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означает эта строчка кода.

```
EnumMap<Symbol, Object> commands = new EnumMap<Symbol, Object>(Symbol.class)
```

Где symbol class

```
public enum Symbol {

    FIRST_DIGIT,
    OPERATION,
    SECOND_DIGIT

}
```

Я подозреваю, что он создает map такой структуры:

```
FIRST_DIGIT =

OPERATION =

SECOND_DIGIT =
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`EnumMap` - это `HashMap` оптимизированный под использование enum'ом.

После строчки:

```
EnumMap<Symbol, Object> commands = new EnumMap<Symbol, Object>(Symbol.class)
```

будет создана пустая хеш-таблица.

Чтобы там что-то лежало, надо ручками добавить, например:

```
commands.put(STATE.FIRST_DIGIT, "I'm digit");
commands.put(STATE.SECOND_DIGIT, "I'm second digit");
commands.put(STATE. OPERATION, "I'm  operation");
```

Передавать тип в конструктор необходимо, так как, я уже говорил, структура оптимизирована для использования enum'ов. Передавая тип ключа в конструктор, мы позволяем на раннем этапе вычислить максимальное число элементов в таблице (так как одинаковых ключей быть не может, а элементы enum'а нельзя изменить динамически).

Comment: меня смущает эта строчка Symbol.class. Мы можем создать EnumMap Без этого параметра?

Comment: @duddeniska обновил ответ, всё ради оптимизации

Comment: аа понятно! т.е. в ключах мы можем использовать только тот enum который я передал в конструктор?

Comment: @duddeniska угу